# Saving tinyMCE value before submiting to php

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, tinymce

I am trying to accomplish this. it does work but I have to submit the form twice before tinyMCE value get stored.

```
$("form#data").on('submit',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        tinymce.init({
            selector: "textarea",
            statusbar: false,
            setup: function (editor) {
                editor.on('change', function () {
                    editor.save();
                });
            }
            });

        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'includes/new_post.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data)
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false

        });

        return false;
    });
```

The Ajax part of the code works perfectly its just that the form like wise other forms but the tinyMCE text area wont submit on first go. if i click the button twice then it will save please assist.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're doing the initializing in the wrong place.

The first time you submit the form, the tinymce gets initialized. Instead you should initialize it on page load.

Comment: I've tried to so that but its no luck same problem.

Answer (score 0):

you should do it like this:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    statusbar: false,
    setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on('change', function () {
            editor.save();
        });
    }
});

$("form#data").on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'includes/new_post.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data)
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false

    });

    return false;
});
```